# How to update mark a form dirty after a server side modification

Tags: frappe

I don't understand how to make the Client ui aware of a server side change in a document.

My use case is the following : I'm adding a button to my form, that calls a custom document method :
[image: The custom button]

In MyDocType.py, I have :

```py
class MyDocType(Document):

    @frappe.whitelist()
    def change_some_value_in_doc(self):

        self.the_field_i_want_to_change = 50
```

It work in the sense that `the_field_i_want_to_change` is immediately updated to the new value.

**However**, If I hit *Save*, I get the message **"No changes in document"**. I managed to determine that this is because on the JS side, the form is not marked as "dirty", but despite reading the documentation over and over, I cannot find the right way.

I tried with `self.notify_update()` which seems to have no effect.

Is it a bug ? Or am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work ?

I'm using frappe v 14.0.0-beta.3

[EDIT]

Actually, I realized that doing

```py
class MyDocType(Document):

    @frappe.whitelist()
    def change_some_value_in_doc(self):

        self.the_field_i_want_to_change = 50
        self.save()
```

Does work in the sense that it save the new value, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for, because my purpose is actually to pre-fill some data with the custom method and **leave to the user** to complete before saving...

Any help to get me in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: I would create a doc with prefilled data then I would use set_route to open/show that doc. Do you need to set this form fields value from different doc?

Comment: You may want to write a Client-side Script for this. You could get this done with server-side scripting too, but I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To pre-fill data in your form - that you want the user to confirm before saving to the database, you should use client-side scripting (in JS). Changing the value on the server is not going to help you since you want the user to get pre-filled values before inserting a record in the database.